# How to generate graphical report from a table?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm fairly new to wordpress and I like to ask on how to do or what plugins to use for a specific task.
I am currently using a table plugin (tablepress) and I'd like to use the data from my input to generate a graph (pie or donut chart). Is there a way (or plugin) I could make it? Also if I want to use that data on other events, do I have to manipulate the database manually? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "TablePress" plugin gives you an option of exporting you tables in CSV format. The "TablePress" stores your table's data in the database in the "posts" table.

After exporting you can use the ["Visualizer" plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/visualizer) to then create charts from the exported CSV file.
Take a read of the ["Visualizer" plugin's knowledge base](http://visualizer.madpixels.net/knowledgebase/) to figure out how to use it.

Reference: 
StackOverflow link relating to Wordpress Charts Plugin - [Wordpress Charts Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892678/wordpress-charts-plugin)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info, although the link you gave to for the knowledge base seems to be down. The site says 'We are coming soon'. Are there any sites I could look for documentation?

Comment: You can look at the Knowledge base section having links in the bottom of the Description of the Visualizer plugin
http://wordpress.org/plugins/visualizer/

or directly here,
https://github.com/madpixelslabs/visualizer/wiki/How-can-I-create-a-chart%3F